# A Set is a collection of well defined and distinct objects. What is a collection of well defined objects without being distinct called?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

> A set is a collection of well defined and distinct objects, considered
>   as an object in its own right.

What is the mathematical term for a collection of well-defined objects without distinction required?

Comment: A [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: @DavidMitra, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so this can be marked as answered: The term for a collection of objects without distinction required is "[multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)".

Comment: Multisets are sometimes known as "bags".