# Name of a set that allows repetition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

If a `set` cannot contain repetition, what would be the proper term for a group of items that allowed repetition?

Comment: Similar question: [A Set is a collection of well defined and distinct objects. What is a collection of well defined objects without being distinct called?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140902/a-set-is-a-collection-of-well-defined-and-distinct-objects-what-is-a-collection)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Multisets are sets which allow repetitions, but the order does not matter.

If you wish to allow repetitions and the order does matter, you are looking for a sequence.

Comment: Multisets are sometimes known as "bags".

Comment: I never heard that terminology; but then again I haven't really worked with multisets.